# Aperture export import script

Tags: applescript, dam

With macOS Catalina dropping support for Aperture, I need to move my library to a different application. Mylio has a great import tool that carries over almost all of the library structure and metadata but loses some of the adjustments. To retain those, I'm trying to write an Apple script that exports all images (with adjustments applied) in my library and reimports them into the same project before deleting the original.

I think I almost have the first part, exporting all images.

```
tell application "Aperture"
  tell library 1
        set projects to (get every project)
        repeat with i from 1 to count of projects
            tell (item i of projects)
                export its every image version naming folders with folder naming policy ¬
                    "Project Name" using export setting ¬
                    "JPEG - Original Size" to (choose folder with prompt "Choose an export folder")
            end tell
        end repeat
  end tell
end tell
```

However, when I try to run this script, I keep getting the error

```
apertureExportImport.applescript:704:712:
execution error: Aperture got an error: Can’t make {project id "1ixjjya6T+Sb3pFmhRK8Fg"} into type project. (-1700)
```

I guess the problem is with `set projects to (get every project)` but I can't find any examples online from which to figure out what else to write here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use *`Aperture`*, so I can only take an educated guess:

From the error message, I can be reasonably sure that `project` is an AppleScript object, specifically an *element* that, from your script, I'll assume belongs to a `library` object.  In that case, there will almost certainly be a plural element form named `"projects"` already defined , which would refer to a collection of (i.e. multiple) elements that are all of type `project`.

Therefore, the following line:

```
set projects to (get every project)
```

is problematic, because you're attempting to redefine a class object that belongs to AppleScript.  In fact, `projects` will be shorthand for `every project`, so this should already be defined in the way that you want, and simply removing this line completely should be sufficient.

On a separate note, it looks like (from you script) the **`export`** command can be passed a collection of objects as its direct parameter, which you’re doing with `export its every image...`.  Assuming this is valid, then it might be able to export all images in all projects at once:

```
tell application "Aperture" to export every image version in every project of library 1 ¬
    naming folders with folder naming policy "Project Name" using export setting ¬
    "JPEG - Original Size" to (choose folder with prompt "Choose an export folder")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried running your script and spent the last hour attempting to fix the error it gives me: `execution error: Aperture got an error: Can’t get folder naming policy "Project Name". (-1728)` and similarly `execution error: Aperture got an error: Can’t get export setting "JPEG - Original Size". (-1728)`. This is quite odd considering that I definitely have an export setting and a folder policy with those exact names.

Comment: If I run `tell application "Aperture"
 activate
 set folderPolicies to name of folder naming policies
 choose from list folderPolicies with prompt "Select a folder naming policy"
 set folderPolicy to (item 1 of result)
end tell`
it even shows me the [list of policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8bGH.png) I'm expecting.

Comment: Those aren’t issues with _my script_, as you’ve put it.  They’re issues with yours, as my script is a copy of yours, save for the attention I’ve given to solving the problem with how `pictures` was being referenced.  So it looks like my script solved your script’s initial problem, but it turns out your script suffers from subsequent problems that you’re now faced with.  As I don’t use _Aperture_, I am not able to give advice on implementing terminology/syntax that is specific to it.

Comment: I might be able to offer some insight if you upload the scripting definition file for _Aperture_ either to a file sharing site that provides a download link, or by copying its contents to an online paste bin, like [**paste.ee**](https://paste.ee).   Normally, it is named after the application, in which case you can run this line of AppleScript to copy its contents to the clipboard to paste into a paste bin: **`set the clipboard to (read (path to resource "Aperture.sdef" in bundle app "Aperture") as "utf8")`**  Then I can understand how _Aperture_ AppleScripts should work and advise you.

Comment: Here's [Aperture's Applescript definition file](https://paste.ee/p/6t7QQ).

Comment: "For now, my best guess is that ..." That throws `Aperture got an error: Can’t make folder naming policy "Project Name" into type integer. (-1700)`.

Comment: This is getting more and more mysterious. This little script works: `tell application "Aperture"
  set imageSel to (get selection)
  export imageSel naming folders with folder naming policy "Project Name" using export setting "JPEG - Original Size" to (choose folder with prompt "Choose an export folder")
end tell`

Comment: Based on the discussion in [this Apple support forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4932911), I thought it might be a sandboxing issue that the script sometimes can't access folder naming policies. I tried the terminal commands in [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4932911?answerId=21662311022#21662311022) but they didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the `.sdef` file. It was helpful for me to reading through it as I now see that `folder naming policy` and `export setting` are class objects, not parameter labels.  Your latest snippet was useful as it works. Our original code both generate the `error -1728`, which is an incorrect reference to a class object. Can you run my snippet again and confirm this error; and likewise with your original code. We both reference `folder naming policy` and `export setting` along a difference inheritance chain, so I just want to know that they are both definitely wrong, and wrong in the same way.

Comment: PS. The output in the `Replies` tab might be more illuminating than the `Results` tab if you're using _Script Editor_.

Comment: Do you mind also confirming these elements are referenced correctly: **1)** `tell app "Aperture" to return the folder naming policy named "Project Name"`; **2)** `tell app "Aperture" to return the export setting named "JPEG - Original Size"`

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me out here. I forgot to report back that I did get the script to work in the meantime. [I posted the final version below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763192/4034025).

Answer (score 2):

I got it working in the end (everything except deleting the original images after exporting and reimporting but that I can simply do manually by flagging or color-coding all images the script will handle).

```
tell application "Aperture"
  with timeout of 86400 seconds
    activate
    set exportSetting to export setting "JPEG - Original Size"
    set folderPolicy to folder naming policy "Project Name"
    set exportFolder to "/Users/<user>/Desktop"
    -- Alternatively, use
    -- set exportFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose an export folder")

    tell library 1
    repeat with proj in projects
      set imageSel to every image version in proj where flagged is true
      export imageSel naming folders with folderPolicy using exportSetting to exportFolder
        set importFolder to exportFolder & "/" & name of proj
        import importFolder by referencing into proj
    end repeat
    end tell
  end timeout
end tell
```

One important lesson that was hard to learn is that `exportSetting` and `folderPolicy` need to be set in the context of the entire library (i.e. at the very start of the script) rather than on a per-project level to avoid the error

```sh
execution error: Aperture got an error: Can’t get folder naming policy "Project Name". (-1728)
```